# iOS7 new update V 7.1(11D167) not compatible in Xcode 5 for development

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5, ios7.1, xcode5.1

I got notification of IOS7 new version V7.1. I have installed on my iPhone 4S. As I am developer my iPhone 4S is not detected in development mode in Xcode 5 SDK. When I opened organizer in Xcode. It shows,

---

**The version of iOS on “iPhone 4S” is not supported by this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here.**

**OS Installed on iPhone 4S
7.1 (11D167)**

---

Hope Apple fix this issue.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need Xcode 5.1.

Comment: Developers should always update to the latest version of Xcode

Comment: @maddy How could i download xcode 5.1. I can's see any specific path. Neither it is not there in Apple developer site.

Comment: There was no notification in Xcode about the new version.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can update to the latest version of Xcode using the OS X App Store application.

**Edit:**

[App Store link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12)

[Developer Center link](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode)

Comment: Man, I wish I'd known that before upgrading iOS. The Xcode download is about 10 times as big as the iOS download. And now I'm at a cafe.

Comment: Can we just click a button within xCode 5.0.1 to make it update itself?

Comment: @PaulG Xcode doesn't have a built in auto-update feature, but OS X has an auto-update feature through the OS X App Store application. The Apple menu -> Software Update... item is a shortcut to the App Store update feature.

Comment: For me there is no update for Xcode, when I go to Mac App Store and go to the Updates Tab.

Comment: If you previously downloaded Xcode directly from Apple it won't appear in the Updates tab, but you can download it from the App Store [here](https://itunes.apple.com/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12) or developer center [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode).

Comment: I would like to say that even faced the above problem once. But then suddenly one day, my xcode 5.0 started detecting iOS 7.1 .. Yay.. i dont know how , but it did, and I am a happy man now :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need Xcode 5.1 to get access for iOS 7.1. Check the [Xcode release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction/Introduction.html) for more info.