# Device ineligible in Xcode 6.1 when device connected powered by iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I am making a Spritekit Swift game in xCode 6.1. We are using iPad device iOS 8.3 to test the game. Right now apple release iOS 8.4 so i upgrade my device 8.3 to 8.4 iOS.
After that when i connect my device to mac and try to select the device to text purpose. It show the Device Ineligible in XCode 6.1.
What is the solution of this problem. May i use my iPad device (iOS 8.4) to test the game?

Comment: upgrade your xcode too....

Comment: I install Xcode 6.4 and run the application. but in xcode 6.4 my device iPad iOS 8.4 show ineligible.

Comment: Did you restart your xcode??? and try to change the destination in  `product->destination`  look at this...http://zachwaugh.me/posts/fixing-xcode-6-3-beta/

Comment: I also change the destination to.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317379/ios7-new-update-v-7-111d167-not-compatible-in-xcode-5-for-development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After install Xcode 6.4. Firstly i run my project on Xcode 6.4. I got a lots of error. Then close Xcode 6.4 and start Xcode 6.1 and clean the project. After clean i successfully run my app by Xcode 6.1 on my iPad device (iOS 8.4). Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

For running apps on iOS 8.4. You need XCode 6.4. So you have to upgrade your XCode 6.1.

OR

You can download XCode 6.4 from apple developer site [here](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/)

Comment: I upgrade my Xcode 6.1 to 6.4. When i run my project in xCode 6.4. A list of error and the Target device iPad also the ineligible device.

Comment: Did you restarted you mac, sometimes it will help.

Comment: Restart your Mac, Wait for a minute, it would be ok.

Answer (score 0):

If device is showing Ineligible, then try to select it from Menubar option as follows:
 **Product->Destination->select your device.**

I hope it will help you.

Comment: I can do this menially too.

Answer (score 0):

Because the current Xcode version does not support iOS 8.4.

All you have to do is, open you App Store, in the Updates tab, upgrade the Xcode.

`App Store -> Updates -> update Xcode`

It's easy.

Answer (score 0):

update your Xcode to support iOS 8.4

Comment: whats the base sdk of your project?

Answer (score 0):

When you are connecting your device with ios version 8.3 and you have x-code 6.1 it means that it is SDK version is 8.1 and that's why it will show you the device ineligible.
So that solving this error you need to upgrade your SDK version to the same device ios version.
if device version is ios 8.3 then SDK version also needs 8.3 . xcode 6.3 will give you SDK version 8.3. Hope it will help you.